# Select is not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

Html code is following :

```
 <div id="container_sizes">
    <div id="size_guide_container" style="width: 100%;">
    <p id="size_dropdown">
    <select id="style_wrapper_dropdown" ">
    </p>
```

I have putted following code in js file

```
 if ($.browser.msie) {
         $('p#size_dropdown select').bind("mouseenter click focus", function
            $(this).css('width', '100px');
         }).bind("change blur", function() {
             $(this).css('width', '100px');
         });
```

I have putted following code in css file

```
    body.styles p#size_dropdown select:focus {
      width: auto;
    }
```

But still the in select drop down  , text is cut off in IE8 .
Please advise how to fix it.

Comment: and remember browser detection is not a good idea

Comment: Please any one advice on above

Comment: your html seems not valid "<select id="style_wrapper_dropdown"></select>"

Comment: @user2214898 may be a screenshot will let us know what your are trying to achive

Comment: How can share screen shot with you ?

Comment: Upload it somewhere. Provide a link.

Comment: Your JS and CSS seem to be contradictory. The JS says "on focus set the width of the select to 100px", and the CSS says "on focus set the width of the select to auto". Why are you using both JS and CSS for the same thing, but with different values?

Comment: @Mr Lister : I have uploaded screen shot here http://www.flickr.com/photos/95804145@N07/8747001681/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: @ArashMilani Please refer this link for knowing issue well http://www.flickr.com/photos/95804145@N07/8747001681/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: The screenshot does not match the HTML you posted here.

Comment: Ok , let me update it with more understandable one

Comment: <div id="container_sizes">
<div id="size_guide_container" style="width: 100%;">
<p id="size_dropdown">
<select id="style_wrapper_dropdown">
<option id="">seleziona una taglia</option>
<option id="805215157">IT 38</option>
<option id="805215427">IT 40</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>

Comment: @MrLister  please find above html code which make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has an extraneous `#` (before the `p`). Remove it.

And the commenters are right too, of course. You have more errors, both in the HTML and in the Javascript.
Also the HTML is incomplete: it doesn't even contain the text that you say gets cut off!

So please provide a more complete code example.

Edit: after seeing the screenshot it's clear that this is simply a matter of IE behaving differently than other browsers.
With Firefox, the width of the dropdown depends on the width of the widest `option` element, and you can set the width of the `option` elements with CSS.
With IE, the dropdown is simply as wide as the `select`, and there is no CSS that can change that. Neither with a stylesheet nor with jQuery.

By the way, next time please post the real code. Your posted HTML, CSS and Javascript all had errors, so we wasted time looking at those.

Comment: @Arash how can i share screen shot with you here ?

Comment: ------------------Please following html code------------------- <div id="container_sizes"> <div id="size_guide_container" style="width: 100%;"> <p id="size_dropdown"> <select id="style_wrapper_dropdown"> <option id="">seleziona una taglia</option> <option id="805215157">IT 38</option> <option id="805215427">IT 40</option> </select> </p> </div> – user2214898 32 secs ago edit

Comment: @Mr.Richhariya I edited my answer now. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: for your kind information, I have shared real code but yes  might  be that you need complete code to analyze the issue.           thanks for your feedback, so there is no remedy of this issue ?